# I am creating an email spammer, for an outstanding cause

Tags: email, server, gmail, postfix-mta, spam

In Cuba, web access is extremely censored, so I created a tool that allows more than 50,000 people to browse the Internet through email. Cubans send me an email with an URL in the subject line, and I email them back with the response. Read more at https://apretaste.com.

It was working like a charm, till the communist government of Cuba started blocking my emails. My solution was rotation.

I started with [Amazon SES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services#Application_services), and I was changing the domain each time it was blocked, but Amazon adds a header to all emails, and once they blocked the header no email from SES was able to reach Cuba any more. The same happened with Mailgun and others, they all add headers.

Currently I am creating Gmail accounts and sending via SMTP, but Google blocks me for no reason and only allows to send 100 emails a day per account. Also I can only create few emails using the same IP address/phone, so I was forced to use anonymous proxies and fake Chinese phones. Now I am fighting a war on two fronts.

An email can be blocked by three parameters: IP address, domain, and email address.

It will be terrific if I can set up my own [Postfix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postfix_(software)) server at a VPS that auto-rotates the IP address. Even better if I can simulate "gmail.com", to avoid purchasing a new domain every day.

All the intents to create what I call "the ultimate sender" just either reach the spam folder or add unwanted headers making it too easy to block. I feel exhausted. I hit a knowledge barrier here.

I know I am crossing to the dark side, but this is for a very good cause. Thousands count on this service as their only source of unbiased news, social network and to feel part of the 21st century.

Can you please help me implementing "the ultimate sender", or pointing to another solution that I may be missing?

Comment: Have you considered another medium that's not so heavily monitored? Maybe send the page as MMS using Twilio or on WhatsApp/Telegram?

Comment: Trust me, whatever we do will become heavily monitored, and email allows tons of content in just one single interaction, so its the best way we had found. Anyways thanks for the idea.

Comment: This question was mentioned and discussed on podcast *.NET Rocks*, [episode 1462](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?ShowNum=1462), 2017-07-27 (*"GraphQL with Steve Faulkner"*), 00 min 37 secs - 04 min 00 secs. Direct download URL (MP3): [https://traffic.libsyn.com/dotnetrocks/dotnetrocks_1462_graphql.mp3](https://traffic.libsyn.com/dotnetrocks/dotnetrocks_1462_graphql.mp3)

Comment: What about the people on the other end. if they mail urls to some email address won't this trigger some alert in their country, since you say they are being monitored? I can imagine the harsh consequences they could face for sending out urls to your address. Conspiracy against the state is the most common reason to go to jail in such systems. And your system very much makes it look like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My friend, do you remember what made Hillary Clinton lose the last elections to Trump?

It was the "mail" affair. And what was it? People discovered she shared confidential information through a non-official, non-governmental email account (i.e., she used some Gmail, Yahoo or another of a kind). Until here, nothing new with direct relation to your matters. But there is an small particularity on this history, and this can put, maybe not a solution, but maybe a light on a new path you could follow: Clinton actually never **sent** those emails; the email account she used had the password shared and the communication between people (Clinton-someone) occurred only using the **drafts** of the account.

How? One side logs in and accesses the drafts folder. There he/she reads the last message and edits it, cutting and writing new data - then save the draft message. On the next turn, the other side of the communication line logs in and do the same. And so forth, so never really sending those messages, but instead just updating the drafts (this "Hillary" method does schooled people... Dilma Rousseff, impeached ex-president of Brazil, actually did this method down there in Brazil too).

So, maybe if you could establish a pact with your user that he/she doesn't delete the account's password, you could pass those information by this method - without "really" exchanging emails. Maybe a "parent" email account (some that could reset a lost password) could be useful too.

**Alternative**: aren't you able to contract a regular HTTP webserver? You could rely on FTP to publish data to your user, he/she asks for it and you publish a page with that content.

Salvi, have you tried something with Telnet? OK, we are talking here about a text-only environment, but if nothing more would rest in the future, this could be better than nothing. Maybe you could implement a podcast-like, or push-like service based on it. Look what people do with it with references to your walk on the dark side...

1. If in Windows, open your command prompt.
2. Type telnet and press Enter.
3. Type "o" without quotes and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Type "towel.blinkenlights.nl" without the quotes and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Dude the "Hillary" way has a lot of potential. I will think on something along those lines. About FTP, I did not fully get what's in your mind. They can only read/send emails using a government-run email server, and they cannot access the web nor FTP. Maybe I am missing a gold nugget here. Please extend.

Comment: No, it was me that missed a nugget: if your client can't access the web then my "alternate" method gone bad. The idea was you get the info your client wants and paste into a blank page, then save this page, now with the contents your client wants, and publish (ftp) it on your webserver (and then sharing this page url with your client).

Comment: Salvi, have you tried something with telnet? Ok, we are talking here about a text-only environment, but if nothing more would rest in the future, this could be better than nothing. - Please see my **EDIT 2** above about it.

Comment: As far as I know, they cannot reach anything outside Cuba using telnet. Basically all ports are closed but the one to check email, and the requests go directly to a centralized government server. I know the situation is challenging. I do appreciate your ideas here.

Comment: Thank you for your return. I was thinking about two more things, but, same way, just plain and basic ideas, without too much foreseeing nor experiencing on implement such things (and ways I'm sure you've already thought and investigate before, so please pardon me for bugging you). 1) There is a possibility, maybe, that people inside the island have some way to access torrent or emule? Because this "protocols" can do a sort of tunneling...

Comment: 2) Was thinking too about some kind of chat server, maybe behind an https, of course with encryption and some "on the fly" generated password, to avoid fake users (governmental spies, for example). Do not know. Either way I didn't think too much about the real practical and technical consequences, nor about the real defies some kind of implementation would represent... these are just sketch ideas, maybe some ways to investigate possible new forms to workaround your matter - one way or another I'm sure you'll surpass this.

Answer (score 7):

I have a few suggestions for you.

The first one relies on [The Onion Router](https://www.torproject.org/) also known as **Tor**.

Since you are crossing to the dark side, why not also take a look into the darknet?

Take a look at this list of [Tor email providers](https://www.reddit.com/r/emailprivacy/comments/3gf2ta/email_providers_with_onion_tor_hidden_service/). If you have your own email server that can be accessed through **Tor**, it becomes much harder for anybody to stop people from using this service. After all, **Tor** was developed to offer people uncensored access to the web.

You can read about **Tor** in detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)), it uses [Onion Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion_routing) and [this](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en) is how you would set up your server to use **Tor**.

Here is an example how you could use it:

The steps that involve the setup, receiving an URL request and sending back the reply are as follows:

1. **Set up an email server.**
2. **Configure your email server to use Tor.**
3. **Publish the public service name.** (e.g. "duskgytldkxiuqc6.onion")
4. **Deploy a client that takes the service name and a URL, and let it send an email with a request to your server.**
5. **The client now waits for a reply.**
6. **You send a reply and the client receives it.**

You can change your service name on a regular basis, but you need to make it accessible to those who will use this service.

Having an own email server means being able to control the email header.

Here is one example how you could make use of it:

1. **Configure your email server so that it receives and recognizes
   emails which contain the requested URLs.**
2. **Before you send a reply modify the email header so that it shows a random IP address and a random sender email address including a random domain name.**
3. **Send your reply.**

Sending an email that way means that you cannot be replied back to. But since your reply already contains the requested information there is no need to.

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is extremely interesting and I will take a look at it. Thank you for pointing me in this direction.

Comment: Don't mention it! I'm glad I could be of help!

Comment: What about the people on the other end. if they mail urls to some email address won't this trigger some alert in their country, since you say they are being monitored? I can imagine the harsh consequences they could face for sending out urls to your address. Conspiracy against the state is the most common reason to go to jail in such systems. And your system very much makes it look like that.

Answer (score 6):

Crowd source it. 
Find a way that volunteers can send some emails for you. This is the only long term approach that I can think of. A simple web interface with mail to links would be be enough to get started although there are other potential problems with this approach too.

Because you are talking about low numbers of users, you could also use crowdsourcing to create the single email address per person approach. They can create an account on a specific set of email providers and give you the credentials.  This would allow the single email per user approach or could be used to rotate through a large set of email accounts to send emails.

Comment: This is actually a great idea! Thank you, I will give it a serious thought. We have several hundred followers who may be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is perhaps to set up a local SMTP server on your own computer. You don't even need a server per se.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/winsmtpserver/

There are many other such applications. They are usually used to test SMTP functions during local development, but there is nothing against actually sending spam through them.

Comment: Thank you, I use Linux so your link won't work, but I get your point and I can look for similar functionality.

Comment: To "set up" and use and smtp server is the simplest thing on the world as the name already implies. Mail was the whole internet for a long time, it only needs one or more other gateways (proxies) which accepts mail from you, and nothing more. This can be the only question as they can block you based on IP, not much on header because it will depend only on you, being nice or bad. Good luck with your mission supposing you are really on the good side!

Answer (score 2):

I know this would be quite a large task, but how about pairing the users with one or just a few emails so they always receive an email from that email.

1. I'd assume people wouldn't have more than 100 queries per day, if so they could start receiving them from a backup email
2. I'd imagine it would look less suspicious for them to appear to be in constant contact with one unique email rather than 50,000 being in contact with one

I know this would be a huge undertaking, but I feel like it solves your issue.

Comment: Yes, indeed! The problem is to create 50K Gmail/Yahoo/Outlook accounts. I can create 50K different emails using let's say Mailgun, but if they share the same header "X-Sender: Malgun" they will be blocked in 24h. Same problem with creating 50K Gmail/Yahoo aliases. I tried all the above wasting considerable time. If you have an idea to mass create unique email accounts, you may have actually solved my problem :-)

Comment: That's indeed a problem. Yet, considering the nature of the cause, two things can be done. One is to ask Google to help. Another is to ask for some crowd help. I am sure some conservative political communities would gladly help in virtually kicking some Commie ass. Try the alt-right, try 4chan or something. If you can convince them, they will make you a large amount of accounts in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

Since the users are willing to receive emails form you then your shouldn't be blocked.

When you mentioned you are getting block does it mean your mail is going in spam or is getting lost in between sending and receiving or it is getting bounced back??

My suggestion would be to setup your own mail server and follow as below:

-Get approx 25 or more ip to rotate. (IP is the most imp part which is tracked and is accountable for the reputation of your mail server)

- Don't start sending emails in bulk from the word go it is better to gradullay increase the email volume so that mail server reputation nicely built
- keep changing the format of the email often
- encourage user to add yourself to there contact list
- your best part is user are willing to receive emails from you and you would reply to revived email is the USP of yours but still i will recommend you to  register for FBL so that you would know which user is reporting you as spam and you can remove him from your list and never send him email again.
- using best practice to send emails like dkim, SPF, dmarc are also vital.

Hope my answer was of some help to you. If you need step by step guide to step up mail server let me know.

Comment: HI @rajesh, thanks for your response. The one blocking is the Cuban government. Emails were getting to their inboxes just fine, but the Gov just set up rules on their server to drop every email from domain X, or coming from IP Y, or having the header Z. The only domains they cannot entirely block are gmail, yahoo and others like it. I do follow all the best practices you mentioned, but it is hard to keep the rotation while following best practices and attending 50K users at the same time. Any specific idea on how to emulate gmail or solve this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: i will have to check if there is anything else which we can do about it.

Comment: When you say header is tracked I am assuming you ate talking about the host name correct?

Comment: Headers can be the "X-Mailer" header, the "Sender" header, the "X-Sender", the "From" header, you name it. In my experience, as soon as we can emulate the same headers from Gmail we will be fine.

Comment: will it be okay if email goes in spam?

Comment: Yes, our users are very committed, they search for the responses even when they fall as spam

Comment: Okay, I will check further. Usually which email user uses.